# Filtrar valores únicos en columnas R

Tags: r, filtro

Me gustaría crear un dataframe que filtre valores no representados en otras columnas.

Ejemplo: En este dataframe todos los valores de C2, C3, C4 y C5 están en C1, pero no todos los de C1 están en C2, C3, C4 y C5. Quiero seleccionar aquellos valores de C1 que no están en dichas columnas y conservar toda la fila.

```
df

   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
1  a  a  c  a  c
2  b  a  b  b  a
3  c  b  b  a  b
4  d  a  a  a  a
5  e  b  c  c  a
6  f  c  a  b  a
 
df_final

   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
1  d  a  a  a  a
2  e  b  c  c  a
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Si transformas el conjunto de las columnas a comparar en un vector, puedes simplemente usar el `%in%`:

```
df <- read.table(text = "   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
1  a  a  c  a  c
2  b  a  b  b  a
3  c  b  b  a  b
4  d  a  a  a  a
5  e  b  c  c  a
6  f  c  a  b  a")


df[!(df[ ,1] %in% as.matrix(df[ ,-1])), ]

  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
4  d  a  a  a  a
5  e  b  c  c  a
6  f  c  a  b  a
```